# How to add a button to the Main Window Frame Control pane in visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I want to add a button for my Isolated shell application to the Main Frame Control pane in Visual Studio 2013. I am not sure the whether pane is called "Main Window Frame Control", but it is the menu where VS 2013 has the Notifications, Quick Launch and Feedback buttons.

How to add a button to that menu with my extension?

[image]

Comment: A screenshot might be nice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry key that contains the control registrations is at `[ver]_Config\MainWindowFrameControls`.

Searching VS's DLLs (using Telerik's JustDecompile, which has mostly functional full-text search) for "MainWindowFrameControls" turns up the `FrameControlManager` (in the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal assembly and the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI` namespace). That iterates the registry keys, creating a `FrameControl` for each populated by calling its `Read` method. The `Read` method populates a few properties from the registry key, including its `_factoryBundle` field. This contains the GUID of the view factory, view ID, and data source IDs as well (read from the registry key) that will be used to create the control.

The `FrameControl`'s `FrameworkElement` property (which is almost certainly the part that actually gets displayed on the frame) lazily calls `UIFactoryHelper.CreateElementAndDataSource()`, passing it the `_factoryBundle`. This eventually calls `WindowHelper.CreateUIElement`, which hands it off in turn to the [`IVsUiFactory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsuifactory.aspx?ppud=4). Finally, we've reached a (lightly) documented part of VS -- this is part of the public interface.

It turns out that the view GUID of the frame control refers to one of the "UI Providers" [registered by a package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsregisteruifactories.registeruifactory.aspx). (These can also be seen in the registry, under the `_Config\UIProviders` key.)

So in short, you'll need to implement the `IVsUiFactory` interface and register it with the `IVsRegisterUIFactories` service, then expose (with, say, a .pkgdef or more cleanly with a C# custom attribute that does the registry manipulation for you) the corresponding values under a registry key for your control in `MainWindowFrameControls`. This will let you create a custom WPF framework element that gets placed in the main window frame.

I didn't look into databinding, but apparently that's possible too -- just trace the `FrameControl` code until you find out how it works (using a good decompiler -- I like a combination of JustDecompile for its full-text search, and dotPeek for its interface).

---

P.S. Hey, another isolated shell developer! Hi & good luck :-)

Comment: I have implemented  the UIFactory part earlier after looking some decompiled code and dint got it working.Also I dint see the FrameControlManager module earlier, Now picture is some what clear. Will check for the Data binding and the clean Custom attribute for the registry manipulation. Thanks for the answer and tips :)
For UI Providers Registry modification an attribute ProvideUIProvider is used.

Comment: Ah cool, didn't know about `ProvideUIProvider`, that's simpler than my suggestion of writing your attribute. Let me know if you still can't get the UI factory working.

Comment: ProviderUIProvider is not adding keys to MainWIndowFrameControls,Used pkgdef for MainWindowFrameControls reg modification. 
Got the UI factory working after a long debugging. (A misplaced dll and resource issue). Thanks

Comment: I am able to put a button, But the button looks dead. No events working. IF I double click on my button it will resize my Isolated application like a Button is not there. Any idea why this is happening.

Comment: @ted: Hmm, nope, sorry. I've never tried to do this myself. I suggest comparing your code to one of the native button's code to see what's different.